# How to configure spring-data-neo4j with standalone neo4j server?

Tags: java, spring, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I am currently running my webapp with an embedded neo4j. Now I want to change to a standalone neo4j server.
While looking into working with the standalone server I stumbled over spring-data-neo4j. Having worked with spring-data-jpa and remembering how easy it was to connect to a db I started looking for a good tutorial how to work with spring-data-neo4j.

It seems possible with spring-data-neo4j-rest. That leaves the question how to configure it with java config, not with xml.

The [spring data neo4j doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/neo4j/docs/2.3.1.RELEASE/reference/html/tutorial_server.html) doesn't provide any infos on that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You just have to implement a config class that creates a `SpringRestGraphDatabase` with your URL.

Something like:

```
@Configuration
@EnableNeo4jRepositories(basePackages = "org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository")
static class Config extends Neo4jConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public GraphDatabaseService graphDatabaseService() {
        return new SpringRestGraphDatabase("http://localhost:7474/db/data/");
    }
}
```